# Problems Connecting to Database within Docker Image via RStudio using DBI

Tags: r, sql-server, docker, tcp, odbc

I'm attempting to connect to a database within a local Docker image I've spun up using DBI and am running into some pretty cryptic errors... I've successfully started the Docker container (below shows result of `docker ps -a`):

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND             CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
131ab042012c   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/nonr…"   27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes   127.0.0.1:1433->1433/tcp   admiring_northcutt
```

I then try to connect via:

```
pool<- pool::dbPool(odbc::odbc(),
                    Driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                    Server   = "localhost",
                    Database = "master",
                    UID      = "sa",
                    PWD      = "***********",
                    Port     = 1433)
```

and receive the error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

Checking my odbc driver using `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` returns the output below, so the drivers seem to be present.

```
                           name   attribute                                   value
1 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Description Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
2 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server      Driver    /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
3 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server  UsageCount                                       2
```

In addition, executing the container and attempting to connect to the database via the commands:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P '<password>'
```

EDIT: The above method now works and I'm able to actively query within the database. I know that the error can't be due to invalid login credentials because I'm using the same exact ones as I ran above in the container.

This same process works for a coworker, so I'm wondering if it's a local issue with my set up. We already compared our .ini files as suggested in this link and they're identical, I've clean re-installed Docker, and I've even ran the coworker's identical container with no luck. Any ideas what could be happening here?

Computer specs:

> ```
> MacBook Pro (16-inch 2019)
> OS: macOS Monterey (version 12.2.1)
> Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
> Memory: 16GB 2667MHz DDR4
> Startup Disk: Macintosh HD
> Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB
> ```

Rstudio Version: 2021.09.0 Build 351

OpenSSL Version: 1.1

Comment: Does it work if you remove `Port = 1433`?

Answer (score 0):

I realize I more than a year late, but try adding `TrustServerCertificate = "yes"` to your connection definition.

```
                    Driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                    Server   = "localhost",
                    Database = "master",
                    UID      = "sa",
                    PWD      = "***********",
                    Port     = 1433,
                    TrustServerCertificate = "yes")
```